# Anugularjs ng-disabled not working as expected for a button element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, save, click

I have created a new button which should be enabled on loading on page and should get disabled while data on page is getting saved (there is a save button). So basically this new button should be disabled whenever save button is enabled.

Angular code :

```
<input id="save" class="btn " type="button"
                        value="SAVE BUTTON" ng-click="saveData()" ng-disabled="isSaveButtonDisabled"  /> 
<input id="create" class="btn " type="button"                   
                    value="NEW BUTTON" ng-click="createNewButton()" ng-disabled="isCreateButtonDisabled" />
```

In the controller, it is getting attached to scope :

```
$scope.isSaveButtonDisabled= isSaveButtonDisabled;
$scope.isCreateButtonDisabled= isCreateButtonDisabled;
```

and there are two function which defines the value of this attribute :

```
function isSaveButtonDisabled(){
        $scope.isSaveButtonDisabled= true;  
}
function isCreateButtonDisabled(){
        $scope.isCreateButtonDisabled= false;   
}
```

But the Create Button remains disabled, not matter what.

What am i missing?

Comment: The boolean and function name is the same. That won't work at all. Plus, you aren't really toggling the states, jsut setting it to one value.

Comment: The boolean is :  isSaveButtonDisabled and the function called is saveData(). They have different names.

Comment: When you do this: $scope.isSaveButtonDisabled= isSaveButtonDisabled; you are assigning one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both buttons, you have functions defined with the same name as the 'true/false' bool properties? If so, then you need to change the two wrapper functions to something different (possibly disableSaveButton(), disableCreateButton()) and call those two functions in your existing saveData() / createNewButton()

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can call two functions in a  `ng-click`

try this way.

```
$scope.isSaveButtonDisabled= function(){
        $scope.isSaveButtonDisabled= true;
       $scope.isCreateButtonDisabled= false;     
}

$scope.isCreateButtonDisabled= function(){
        $scope.isCreateButtonDisabled= false; 
        $scope.isSaveButtonDisabled= true;  
}
```

Kindly change your code in HTML, like

```
<input id="save" class="btn " type="button"
                        value="SAVE BUTTON" ng-click="isSaveButtonDisabled();saveData();" ng-disabled="isSaveButtonDisabled"  /> 
<input id="create" class="btn " type="button"                   
                    value="NEW BUTTON" ng-click="isCreateButtonDisabled();createNewButton();" ng-disabled="isCreateButtonDisabled" />
```

Comment: The ng-click() is supposed to call different functions saveData() and createNewButton() as shown in the code.

Comment: @user3772144 .I have changed my answer as what you expect :)

Comment: i do not want the ng-disabled to be activated on button click, i want it to be activated on page load.

Comment: Thanks for your help